# Is there a web browser addon to view mysql database?

Tags: mysql

I am looking forward to a tool to view a mysql database like a browser addon without installing a heavy software..

If there is any other software you want to suggest for viewing and editing mysql database please post your suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

[phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) is a typical choice.  You do need a PHP-enabled web server, but that's pretty easy, and then you get a browser-based interface for interacting with your MySQL server.

It's obviously not a browser add-on, but the software requirements aren't all that unusual.

Answer (score 3):

[PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) will probably be what you need. It's not a browser add-on, though. It installs on the server.

Answer (score 2):

[Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/) is a simpler alternative to PHPMyAdmin

Comment: This is indeed a nice alternative to PMA. Nice recommendation.